# How can I set up a Flask server in PythonAnywhere to receive an HTTP GET request that includes a cookie and store the information from the request?

Tags: python, flask, server, httprequest, pythonanywhere

I don't know how to make a flask server to receive this request.

```
cookie = "anything"
token = requests.get(f"http://ex.example.com/{cookie}")
if token.text=="VALID":
    #something
```

I don't know how to make a flask server to receive this request. I use pythonanywhere

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet will create a flask server with expected behaviour.

```
from flask import Flask
from markupsafe import escape

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<cookie>')
def biscuits(cookie):
    something = escape(cookie)
    if something == "anything":
        return 'VALID'
    return 'INVALID'
```

save above code to a file, then execute `flask run` command from same directory. this will create a development server on 127.0.0.1:5000 address.

P.S. To be able to receive requests on  `ex.example.com` domain, you need to add such line to `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 ex.example.com
```

also set port option to 80 (or 443) when running server.